# IntelliJ Ultimate Detects Ruby On Rails as JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

Searching on the jetbrains website, I came up with this: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/configuring-ruby-sdk.html. However, I don't have the Ruby SDK pane. I have set the project to have the Project SDK for the version of Ruby installed, the Modules->Dependencies has the version of Ruby selected, but each time the project loads, it prompts me to set the framework to JRuby. It's not a JRuby project. Granted, I don't have RubyMine, but I thought that that was the purpose of Ultimate, to be an all-in-one.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe a late response, but here's answer anyway. I stumbled upon the same issue while evaluating the Ultimate version.

To fix the "JRuby on Rails framework detected" issue, just create a new project "from existing sources". Follow the steps in the wizard and "Ruby on Rails" framework will be detected correctly - no more JRuby...

Hope it helps!